# Node.js Route.post()

Tags: node.js, function, object, npm, callback

I'm writing a Node.js application and I'm trying to use functions from my index.js file inside the calls.js controller. Whenever I add

```
var IndexBot = require('/root/afstudeerwerk/chatbotPIROS/index');
```

To my calls.js file I get the following error:
error1:
[image: error1]

routes.js (/root/afstudeerwerk/chatbotApi/api/routes):

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
var chatbot = require('/root/afstudeerwerk/chatbotPIROS/calls');

app.post('/slack/receive',chatbot.create_a_message);
app.post('/DBcheck/:id',chatbot.checkUserAuth);
};
```

calls.js (/root/afstudeerwerk/chatbotPIROS/calls)

```
'use strict';
exports.create_a_message = function(req, res) {
var IndexBot = require('/root/afstudeerwerk/chatbotPIROS/index');
var message = req.body;

var button = JSON.parse(message.payload).actions[0].value

if(button == 'MeanMakeVM'){
        res.json({message:'Please enter your VM specs.'});
        IndexBot.stuur_bot_bericht('dit is een testbericht.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have any method missing in your controller for which you have given route in routes filefile.

In your routes file you have a route `app.post('/DBcheck/:id',chatbot.checkUserAuth);` but it does not have any function named checkUserAuth in `calls.js` that's why it is giving you error.

Create a method named checkUserAuth in calls file and your error will resolve